# C#: "Unable to load" file error on executing System.IO.File.WriteAllLines( ls_PathAndFile, ls_aLineText )

Tags: c#, system.io.file, file.readalllines

While overwriting an xml file through following steps:

1. Read all contents of an xml file in an string array: string[]
   ls_aLineText = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines( ls_PathAndFile );
2. Overwritten contents of the ls_aLineText array
3. Overwriting the xml file using:  System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
   ls_PathAndFile, ls_aLineText );

Steps 1 and 2 execute correctly, but step 3 displays the error "Unable to load" xml file.
Please suggest ways to overcome this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Vivek

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you have write rights on that file?